# concatenating strings using "+" in c++

Tags: c++, string, operators

I am a novice in C++ and i am referring Accelerated C++. While trying one of its exercise questions which says:

```
Are the following definitions valid? Why or why not?
const std::string exclam = "!";
const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;
```

When i tried & executed the program i am getting an error as:

> invalid operands of types to binary operator +.

But the following code works perfectly fine:

```
const std::string hello = "Hello";
const std::string message = hello + ", world" + "!";
```

I am not clear with its execution! why this concatenation in the first case not working?

Thanks!I am using DEV C++.

Comment: `+` is overloaded for `std::string` (which is why the second example works). The first example is trying to use `+` on two string literals (`"Hello"` and `", world"` are not `std::string` objects).

Comment: The answers below explain why the code doesn't work; I'm adding another way to fix the code. You can change the order of operations by adding parentheses that ensure `std::string::operator+` is called for all concatenations. `const std::string message = "Hello" + (", world" + exclam);` But in this case it is better to concatenate the literals by simply getting rid of the `+` in between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first expression

```
"Hello" + ", world"
```

the compiler needs to find a suitable function such as `operator+(const char *, const char *)`.
No such function exists, so it cannot compile.

Conversely,

```
hello + ", world"
```

is looking for one matching `operator+(const std::string&, const char*)`, and that overload *does* exist (it is provided by `std::string`).

---

Note that you even if you *could* write your own overload:

```
std::string operator+ (const char *left, const char *right)
{
    return std::string(left) + right;
}
```

(and you can't, as Praetorian points out) it wouldn't be a good idea.

Firstly, with primitive arguments, you'd lose ADL (ie, if the standard library put the operator in namespace `std`, it wouldn't normally be visible outside).

Secondly, if you have *other* libraries with their own string representations (eg. pre-STL stuff like RogueWave, or Qt, etc. etc.) they'd be equally justified in providing an overload for *their* string type, and the compiler would have no way to choose between them.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `std::string operator+(char const*, char const*)` overload? You may be [surprised](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/cant-replace-ops-on-built-ins.html) ...

Comment: Doh, I wrote that terribly, just a sec ...

Answer (score 3):

It's because `"Hello"` is not, when the compiler reads it, a `std::string`, but `const char *` - which means you can't use it for `+`.

You can trivial fix it with:

```
 const std::string message = std::string("Hello") + ...
```

Comment: @0x499602D2: The result of bad typing... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`"Hello"` is not a string, in the sense that it's not an object of type `std::string`. It's a *string literal*, which is an array of characters. You can't concatenate two literals with `+`, but you can concatenate a `std::string` with an array (and vice versa).

`"Hello" + ", world" + exclam` is equivalent to `("Hello" + ", world") + exclam`, and so doesn't work because it tries to concatenate two literals. However, you could concatenate them without the `+` operator: `"Hello" ", world" + exclam`

`hello + ", world" + "!";` is equivalent to `(hello + ", world") + "!"`. It concatenates a `std::string` with a literal; the result is a new `std::string` which is then concatenated with the second literal. Both concatenations are allowed.

The reason is that C++ is a member of a language family that has slowly evolved over the last half century or so, and still has vestigial remnants of ancient languages around the edges.

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello"` and `", world"` in the first example are const char* objects. There is no defined way to add two character arrays together due to the nature of pointers, although logically it seems fine.

In the second example, hello is a std::string objects which has a + operator defined so that when you write:

```
hello + ", world"
```

it creates a new std::string object containing both pieces of content.