# Why is g++ allowing me to treat this void-function as anything but?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Why does the following compile in GCC 4.8 (`g++`)? Isn't it completely ill-formed?

```
void test(int x)
{
    return test(3);
}

int main() {}
```

1. I'm trying to use the result of calling `test`, which does not exist
2. I'm trying to return a value from `test`

Both should be fundamentally impossible — not just UB, as far as I can recall — with a `void` return type.

The only warning I get is about `x` being unused, not even anything about a non-standard implicit return type being added.

### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26ef5111fe0abf9f)

Comment: It's not about objects being of type `void`. *Expressions* of type `void` are *discarded-value expressions*.

Comment: once you call the function however it should result in a `Segmentation fault`

Comment: @dan: Or a stack overflow, or some other practical consequence of a non-terminating program with infinite call depth. That could include my program spontaneously developing sentience and telephoning you at work. :)

Comment: Note: That's not specific to C++11. Since C++98/03 have we been able to write `return f();` instead of `{ f(); return; }` (given `void f();`). TC++PL3 §7.3 (page 148) said “This form of return is important when writing template functions where the return type is a template parameter”.

Comment: `void` has been an incomplete type since C++98. Can you please provide information about `void` not being incomplete in C++11 anymore?

Comment: @gx_ dammit, why didn't you put that as an answer :) It wouldn't make me look as someone hunting for rep and copying comments!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'm wrong. `[C++03: 3.9/5]` and `[C++11: 3.9/6]` both state that `void` is incomplete. There is some rule that changes how `void` is handled in C++11, but I can't remember what it is. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit all that I can remember about `void` is that you can do `void f(TypedefForVoid);` now (and I also forgot whether this change was for C++11 or whether it will be for C++14).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Apparently I was thinking of `void` being made a literal type in C++14, as discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20492630/560648) that I nonetheless deleted because it wasn't quite right for the stated question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's allowed by the standard (§6.6.3/3)

> A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in functions with a return type of cv void; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. The entire thing becomes a no-op. Worth noting that this was the same in C++03, and that it's bloody stupid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm guessing it's useful in templates where the return type might or might not be `void`.

Comment: @Mat: I think I'd still have hoped for ill-formity there, and let SFINAE open up other options. If nothing else though it just makes this _really_ horrid for non-template code. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm guessing you can't switch to C, which forbids this? (-:

Comment: It could have its uses.  Given a function `void error_reporter(...)`, you can write code in a function that returns `void` just: `if (something > sommat_else) return error_reporter("the impossible occurred");` instead of needing braces and multiple statements inside them.  That could be quite useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Mmm I suppose but I still think it's more surprising than it is useful.

Answer (score 6):

As to why GCC allows it - sure because the Standard requires it to be valid. Building the transitive closure to the rationale of the rule in the Standard, I'm pretty sure that GCC allows this because it's useful in the event of templates

```
template<typename F>
typename std::result_of<F()>::type call(F f) {
  return f();
}

int main() {
   std::cout << call([]{ return 42; }) << std::endl;
   call([]{ std::cout << "I'm just an outputtor!" << std::endl; });
}
```

As you see, `call` did not need to do a special case for `void` in the return statement. Sort of similar to how `x.~T()` is allowed even if `T` ends up as `int`.